# Finding a maximum value in a row using row name and reporting the found value and column name

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains four countries and three variable x,y,z. Now I'm trying to create a function that returns the highest value of the defined row and the column name which contains the highest value in the row.

```
           x           y          z 
Sweden  1.6534561  0.11523404  0.2261730 
France -1.2274320 -0.24096054  1.5096028
England -1.4503096  0.07227427  1.6740867
Spain  0.1867416  1.25318913 -0.7350560
```

The problem is I don't understand how I could use the row_name in finding the highest value in that row.

```
my_function(row_name){

value=
column=

paste("Highest value is", value, "and it is in column", column)
}
```

For example

`my_function("Sweden"`) should return "Highest value is 1.6534561 and is in column x"

Comment: Please accept answers to all previous questions if those answers helped you to solve the problem. You can accept an answer by clicking the "tick" if and only if it is the "best" solution according to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(ID= row.names(.)) %>% 
   tidyr::gather(key,val,-ID) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(val==max(val))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
  ID      key     val
  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
1 Sweden  x      1.65
2 Spain   y      1.25
3 France  z      1.51
4 England z      1.67
```

To make a function(**Note that this might require some non standard evaluation**),

```
max_finder <- function(df, target_id){

   df %>% 
     mutate(ID= row.names(.)) %>% 
     tidyr::gather(key,val,-ID) %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     filter(val==max(val), ID ==target_id)

 }



max_finder(df,"Sweden")
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   ID [1]
  ID     key     val
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 Sweden x      1.65
```

**Data**:

```
df<- structure(list(x = c(1.6534561, -1.227432, -1.4503096, 0.1867416
    ), y = c(0.11523404, -0.24096054, 0.07227427, 1.25318913), z = c(0.226173, 
    1.5096028, 1.6740867, -0.735056)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Sweden", 
    "France", "England", "Spain"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple dataset that is not identical but very similar to yours.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(x = 1:4, y = c(4, 8, 1, 6), z = c(3, 4, 1, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Sweden", 
"France", "England", "Spain"))
```

The function utilizes basic indexing and requires you to additionally specify the `data.frame`, you can remove this feature if you wish.

**Function**

```
my_function <- function(Row, df){
 max <- max(df[Row, ])
 row <- which(df[Row, ] == max)
 paste("Highest value is", max, "and it is in column", names(df)[row])
}

> my_function("Sweden", df)
[1] "Highest value is 4 and it is in column y"
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
my_function(row_name){

value=max(dataframe["row_name", ])
for(i in c(1:length(a["row_name",])) {
if(a["row_name",i] == value
column=names(dataframe)[i]
}
paste("Highest value is", value, "and it is in column", column)
}
```